# How to scrape data after scrolling the page down, a page which only loads 10 items and then when we scroll down it will add the items

Tags: python, html, selenium

https://www.fynd.com/brands/
I am trying to scrape the data from this page and get all the data in the title div tag, but there are many title tags as you scroll down. Initially, when we load the page it will only show a few brands and then when we manually scroll down it will keep on adding brands. The below code is what I am using :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

url = "https://www.fynd.com/brands/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="D:\\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
title = soup.find_all('span', class_="ukt-title clrWhite")
all_titles = list()
for jelly in title:
    all_titles.append(jelly.text.strip())
    
print(all_titles)
```

[Screenshot of the titles which I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJudQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code :

It's an infinite while loop for list of `webelements`. Make sure to have the  same indentation :

```
driver.get("https://www.fynd.com/brands/")
while True:
    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-cardtype='BRANDS']"):
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
      sleep(0.1)
      print(item.text)
```

You can optimize this script by removing `0.1` , I just put to have a visual experience.

Comment: This is partially working, it is only extracting 12 brands, if you check the page and scroll down, new brands will appear as you go on scrolling down and there are 515 brands in total listed on that page. That is what I am trying to fetch. The code which I have and the code which you wrote only fetches 12 brands.

Answer (score 0):

### its a little bit different but working

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
i=0
f = open('yeshivaLinks.txt','w')

driver.get("https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/filter")
print (len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myLessonsScroller"]/ul/content-preview/a')))

for a in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myLessonsScroller"]/ul/content-preview/a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))

while True:
  for a in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myLessonsScroller"]/ul/content-preview/a'):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a).perform()
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
    f.write(a.get_attribute('href')+'\n')
    i= i+1
    if(i == (len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="myLessonsScroller"]/ul/content-preview/a')[i:])-15)):
      for i in range(10):
        lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print(lastHeight)
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-50);')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this.

```
driver.get("https://www.fynd.com/brands/")
while True:
    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-cardtype='BRANDS']"):
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
      sleep(0.5)
      print(item.text)
```

Comment: it's the same code and it doesn't auto-scroll down to the end of the webpage, as well as it doesn't register all the brand names

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels")
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
itemTargetCount = 300
cost = []
while itemTargetCount > len(cost):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'hlistpg_hotel_shown_price')
    textElements = []
    for i in range(len(elements)):
        textElements.append(elements[i].text)
    cost = textElements
print(cost)
print(len(cost))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).